# my $_SESSION["message"] echoing everywhere even there is if

Tags: php, session

I have one problem.I wanted to echo my message ("subject created", "subject creation failed" depending on whether  my subject is created or not). The problem is the message is on every page even though setting the `$_SESSION["message"]` is under `if` condition . I really don't know where is the problem. I lost probably 2 hours on this...

All includes and requires are included...

This is on my proceeding page:

```
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $menu_name = mysql_prep($_POST["menu_name"]);
        $position = (int) $_POST["position"];
        $visible = (int) $_POST["visible"];

        $query  = "INSERT INTO subjects(";
        $query .= " menu_name, position, visible ";
        $query .= ") VALUES ('{$menu_name}', '{$position}', '{$visible}')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if($result) {
            //success //
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Subject created";
            redirect_to("manage_content.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Subject creation failed";
            redirect_to("create_new_content.php");
        }
} else {            
        redirect_to("create_new_content.php");
}
```

my message function is:

```
session_start();
function message() {
            if (isset($_SESSION["message"])){
                $output = $_SESSION["message"];
                return $output;
                }
}
```

and after all Im echoing on my `manage_content.php` and `create_new_content.php`

```
<?php echo message();  ?>
```

Comment: if you show your message only one time, you need to clear the `$_SESSION["message"]` before return.

Comment: I figured it out.I should put $_SESSION["message"] = null before return the $output in message()

Comment: yes... like `$output = $_SESSION["message"]; $_SESSION["message"] = null; unset($_SESSION["message"]); return $output;` i will write a answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clear the session when its not needed any more.

E.g.

`unset($_SESSION['message']);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your $_SESSION message and check if is not empty

```
function message() {
        if (isset($_SESSION["message"]) && !empty($_SESSION["message"])){
            $output = $_SESSION["message"];
            $_SESSION["message"] = '';
            return $output;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you show your message only one time, you need to clear the $_SESSION["message"] before `return`

```
session_start();

function message() {
    if (isset($_SESSION["message"])){
        $output = $_SESSION["message"];

        // clear the session message
        $_SESSION["message"] = null;

        // remove message index from $_SESSION
        unset($_SESSION["message"]);

        return $output;
    }
}
```